# Can we overwrite the login functionality of Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

When we setup the Laravel authentication functionality it will automatically create route login and login functionality.

Can we change that route login functionality and add to our created controller functionality?

Can we write route login in our routes/web.php file and change the logincontroller to our customercontroller?

Comment: Yes, You definitely can but why?

Comment: Yes off course you can change according to your wish. But, I don't think `customerController` is a good name for login functionality. What say you?

Comment: Thanks, Yes i solved the problem by copying LoginController and give name CustomerLoginController in Auth folder. It's works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can we change that route login functionality and add to our created controller functionality? Blockquote

Whan do you mean by word functionality?

1. If you want override action at route 'login' change in routes Route::get('login', 'YourTestController@someAction')->name('login');
2. If you want to change behaviour then you should change App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController(redirect or set additional middleware)
3. If you want to change the type of authorization(for example check user from Action Directory or custom auth. server) you should create your CustomUserProvider derived from interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider and so on.

Comment: I wrote blow lines in routes/web.php
Route::get('/login', 'CustomerController@login')->name('login');
Route::post('/login', 'CustomerController@loginsubmit')->name('login.submit');
but it shows me "The page isn’t redirecting properly" page.

Comment: I solve the problem by copying LoginController and give name CustomerLoginController in Auth folder. It's works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use your custom controllers for login. For example, to check a user password and log him in, you can use the following code in a controller method:

```
if (!Auth::attempt([
    'email' => $request->input('login'),
    'password' => $request->input('password')
])) {
    abort(422, 'Incorrect login & password');
}

return response()->json([
    'redirectURL' => $request->session()->pull('url.intended', url('/'))
]);
```

Where `email` and `password` are User model fields (`password` stores a password hash).

Then you can add this controller method to the routes in the `routes/web.php` file like a regular route.

To log the user out just call:

```
Auth::logout();
```

You can find more information about the manual authentication in the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/authentication#authenticating-users).